# Why adonis is giving significant p value even though confidence ellipses of NMDS plot is overlapping?

Tags: r

I have done NMDS plot and adonis for species composition data between two groups.  adonis is giving me a significant p value indicating that the species composition between two groups are significantly different. But in the NMDS plot confidence ellipses of two groups are overlapping indicating that there is no difference between two groups.
Is it correct to write that the species composition between two  groups are significantly  different?

Comment: With this type of statistics question you will have better luck over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/; unless you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your own efforts to interrogate/solve your problem it will likely be closed as it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.